# Unable to launch Google Chrome when Intellij IDEA opened as root

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, ubuntu-16.04, intellij-idea-2018

I am unable to view my html page in google-chrome or any browser from Intellij IDEA 2018 using the shortcut provided in the top-right side. This is how i was trying to open:

[image]

I can use this shortcut only if i have opened Intellij without being the root user. I am using `sudo ./idea.sh` command to launch Intellij from the folder `~/Installed/idea-IU-183.5912.21/bin`. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04. Please help.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/175969/9113) help? Why do you need to run IntelliJ IDEA as root?

Comment: I am launching my server from intellij directly in 80 and 443 for testing purpose.

Comment: I'd suggest using a reverse proxy like `nginx` for proxying port 80 to 8080 instead. It can also proxy SSL.

Comment: I have seen people using reverse proxy using nginx but i don't understand why should i use if i could do all the things i want using the embedded undertow server. Would you like to provide a brief explanation

Comment: So that you don't have to run IntelliJ IDEA and Chrome as root.

Comment: Other than that, is it safe to use in production with implementing reverse proxy.

Comment: Sure, a lot of web resources you access every day are actually behind `nginx` or some other reverse proxy.